# Can I travel within the USA with 3 months left to my passport but valid student visa?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passports, study, filipino-citizens

I have booked a flight in 20-28th March to go to Hawaii from Seattle. My Philippine passports current expiry date is 23th June 2016. My USA student visa and Form I-20 has until Sept 2019. I am still waiting for my new passport from the Philippine consulate in San Francisco but I am not sure if I will get it before I leave. 
Will this be an issue for me? I am traveling within the USA with a valid Visa and just a really tight life line on my passport. Thanks

Comment: Are you staying in Hawaii until your passport expires?

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you need to travel within the US is a TSA-accepted form of ID, of which an unexpired passport is one. Your passport can serve as an ID for TSA purposes until the day it expires. So you should be fine.